# Fix missing KDE oxygen icons on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, kde

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 and used the KDE human theme in 11.10.

After upgrade I switched back to oxygen-icon-theme and many KDE icons are still missing.

I've already tried to reinstall oxygen-icon-theme.

Here a screenshot from German Krusader menu. You see a lot of icons missing.

How to restore default Ubuntu 12.04 KDE icons?

[image: Missing oxygen icons]

Answer (score 1):

```
mv ~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals ~/.kde/share/config/kdeglobals.yedek
```

this solved the problem for me.